# Connected components of $X=\{0\}\cup\{2^n:n\in\Bbb{Z}\}$

Tags: general-topology

Give $\Bbb{R}$ the standard topology and give $X$ the subspace topology.

I need to show that $X$ has infinitely many connected components but I am so confused. I cant seem to find even one connected subset of $X$ let alone a connected component.

Can some one give me a hint on how to begin constructing a connected subset of $X$ so I can at least get an idea of their structure before trying to show that there are infinitely many of them.

I have worked hard to answer this, the problem seems to be that X is discrete in its nature and so whenever I consider a subset of X, I end being able to split it up and conclude its disconnected.

Comment: Most lone points like $\{2^1\}$ qualify as connected components here.

Comment: I just realised my mistake, I was considering $\{2\}$ to be disconnected since $\{2\}=\{2\}\cup\emptyset$ but I forgot you cant use the empty set. Thanks